# Passing Object to Loopback Models

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Wondering if there is a correct way to give loopback models access to certain objects that are created alongside the main app.

example:
We have a emailService and upon certain events on models we would want to send relevant data to this service.

Right now my current solution is this

server.js

```
const app = loopback()
const email = createEmailService()
app.emailS = email
```

myModel.js

```
myModel.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    myModel.app.emailS.send('example@test.com', ctx.instance.message)
}
```

Hoping theres better way than having to set the client to the app object.  Since other models are accessed via myModel.app.models.OtherModel I take it my approach is alright but maybe not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Well this works fine in most cases, although you have to be careful that it doesn't conflict with other properties in the app object and as loopback project grows they might add more properties to it, so keep an eye on it.

My own preference is to actually put it into a module:

server/email-service.js

```
...
module.exports = createEmailService();
```

common/models/myModel.js

```
const emailS = require('../../server/email-service');
myModel.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    emailS.send('example@test.com', ctx.instance.message)
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about polluting the loopback namespace.